# vue passing computed value to a button`s method @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've just started learning vuejs. And I've got troubles with passing a value to a button's `@click` method.

Here is where I want to pass the value in the template

```
<v-btn @click="deleteCityWithId(city.id)">
   Delete
</v-btn>
```

and here is where I have the city

```
computed: mapGetters(['city']),
```

computed values perfectly worked in v-for loop but here I can't get access to it.

How can I pass the value in click handler?

Comment: This syntax for a computed is strange. Is `mapGetters` returning an object of schema `{ city: { id: 123 } }`? I'd expect to see a computed defined like `computed: { city: function() { return { id: 123 }} }`.. apologies if this is some shorthand syntax that I don't know about.

Comment: let imagine that it`s the same  { city: function() { return { id: 123 }} } How to get this value in click handler?

Comment: possibly `$data.city.id`. The computed is also accessible inside the click handler itself as `this.city.id` (which perhaps you already know).

Comment: Is this button inside of the for loop you mentioned? If so, edit your code to show that loop with this button. I think we are going to need more code to reproduce this, so if you can add code that reproduces the problem, we can better help you solve it.

Comment: Why don't use that getter inside function without passing to it? Or city getter is array?